# Creating or getting a burndown chart with JIRA GreenHopper API

Tags: silverlight, jira, greenhopper

We're having the JIRA GreenHopper Agile extension installed.

Using the web interface of JIRA it is possible to take a look at burndown charts.

I'm having a Silverlight app, where I want to display a burndown chart based on the data in JIRA. This, can be done only if I in the SL app hardcode a date interval and what sprint I want the burndown chart for. Not as dynamic as I want it to be.

Is there a way to find out which sprint is the current sprint, the start date and end date of a sprint using the API? Without this information it seems difficult to create a burndown chart at all with the GreenHopper API.

Or do you guys have an even better idea how to proceed to be able to get that burndown chart.

Any help or advice is appreciated, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interfacing with JIRA 4.3, you might have a look at the 
'earliestUnreleasedVersion' JQL function:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-earliestUnreleasedVersion

This provides you the next version that is due to be released.

Of course this is assuming that you can use JQL functions from SL.

Francis

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use versions to manage your sprints. In this case, you can use the 'getVersions' function and from the result find the version that is not yet release and/or the start- enddate includes today.